# Clockify- CreateProjectAsync with Memberships

Tags: clockify

I'm having a error when I use c# API clockify

When I create a Project with Memberships I get this error:
`"{\"message\":\"Internal server error.\",\"code\":500}"`

When i comment Memberships attribute the project it's created.

```
var assignees = new List<MembershipRequest>();
var member = new MembershipRequest();
member.MembershipStatus = MembershipStatus.Active;
member.MembershipType = "PROJECT";
member.UserId = "UserId";
assignees.Add(member);
var project = new ProjectRequest
{
    Name = "ProjetName",
    ClientId = "ClienteID",
    IsPublic = false,
    Billable = true,
    Color = "#000000",
    Memberships = assignees
};
var clockify = new ClockifyClient("APIKey");
var response = await clockify.CreateProjectAsync("WorkSpaceID", project).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Memberships are a nested object.

So if it would work,  the code would be

```
{
  Name = "ProjetName",
  ClientId = "ClienteID",
  IsPublic = false,
  Billable = true,
  Color = "#000000",
  "memberships": [{
    "userId": assignee
  }]
}
```

However this is not included in the endpoint, so what I did to make this work was:

`PATCH /workspaces/{workspaceId}/projects/{projectId}/memberships`

```
{
  "memberships": [
    {
      "userId": assignee
    }
  ]
}
```